# How to add ActionListener to JFrame , without using Buttons and Panels?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, listener, actionlistener

I'm writing a Shooter (FPS - First person shooter) and I'm using OpenGl (jogl 1.0) 
with JFrame .

I want to add an ActionListener to the JFrame :

```
public class Main extends JDialog { 

private static ActionListener action;
private static JFrame framePhaseOne;
private static JFrame framePhaseTwo;
...
...


                action  = new ActionListener()      // this is for PHASE 2
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                    {
                        if (userPoints.getGamePhase())  // if F2 was clicked 
                        {
                            framePhaseTwo = new JFrame(WorldName2);
                            framePhaseTwo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
                            framePhaseTwo.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                            framePhaseTwo.setLocation(FRAME_LOCATION_X, FRAME_LOCATION_Y);
                            Renderer_PhaseTwo myCanvas2 = new Renderer_PhaseTwo(userPoints);
                            final Animator animator2 = new Animator(myCanvas2);
                            framePhaseTwo.add(myCanvas2);
                            framePhaseTwo.setSize(FRAME_SIZE_X, FRAME_SIZE_Y);
                            framePhaseTwo.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
                                {
                                    new Thread() 
                                    {
                                         @Override
                                         public void run() 
                                         {
                                             animator2.stop();
                                             System.exit(0);
                                         }
                                    }.start();
                                }
                            });

                            framePhaseTwo.setVisible(true);
                            animator2.start();
                            myCanvas2.requestFocus();
                            myCanvas2.setFocusable(true);
                        }
                    }
                };
```

I want to add `action` to `framePhaseOne` , how can I do that , without using JPanel and buttons ?

Here is the full code if Main class , if needed :

```
/**
 * This is the main class that runs the First Person Java app 
 * using the OpenGL mechanism , with JOGL 1.0 
 * @author X2
 *
 */
public class Main extends JDialog
{   

    // when true permission granted for starting the game 
    private static boolean start = false; 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected static TimerThread timerThread;
    static JStatusBar statusBar = new JStatusBar();
    private static JFrame framePhaseOne;
    private static JFrame framePhaseTwo;
    private static ActionListener action;

    /**
     *  framePhaseOne properties
     */

    private static final int FRAME_LOCATION_X = 300;
    private static final int FRAME_LOCATION_Y = 50;
    private static final int FRAME_SIZE_X = 850; // animator's target frames per second
    private static final int FRAME_SIZE_Y = 700; // animator's target frames per second

    /**
     * start button properties
     */

    private static final int BUTTON_LOCATION_X = (FRAME_SIZE_X / 2) - 100;
    private static final int BUTTON_LOCATION_Y = (FRAME_SIZE_Y / 2) - 50; 
    private static final int BUTTON_SIZE_X = 140; // animator's target frames per second
    private static final int BUTTON_SIZE_Y = 50; // animator's target frames per second


    /**
     *  timer & game title & arrow picture
     */

    private static final String WorldName1 = "FPS 2013 CG Project - Phase 1";
    private static final String WorldName2 = "FPS 2013 CG Project - Phase 2";
    private static final String HARD_TARGET = "src/res/target.jpg";
    private static final String runningOut = "Time is running out - you have : ";

    static int interval;
    static Timer timer1;
    static JLabel changingLabel1 = null;

    static Points userPoints = new Points(); 


    /**
     *  Timer properties
     */

    private static Timer timer;
    private static int count = 60;

    /**
     * ActionListener for timer
     */
    private static ActionListener timerAction = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            if (start)
            {
                count--;
                if (count == 0)
                    timer.stop();
                changingLabel1.setText(runningOut + count + " seconds" + " , and your points are: " 
                        + userPoints.getPoints()); 
            }

        }
    };


    public static void exitProcedure() {
        System.out.println();
        timerThread.setRunning(false);
        System.exit(0);
    }


        /**
         * Clock timer1 
         * @author X2
         *
         */
        public static class TimerThread extends Thread 
        {

            protected boolean isRunning;

            protected JLabel dateLabel;
            protected JLabel timeLabel;

            protected SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = 
                    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy");
            protected SimpleDateFormat timeFormat =
                    new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");

            public TimerThread(JLabel dateLabel, JLabel timeLabel) {
                this.dateLabel = dateLabel;
                this.timeLabel = timeLabel;
                this.isRunning = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (isRunning) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            Date currentTime = currentCalendar.getTime();
                            dateLabel.setText(dateFormat.format(currentTime));
                            timeLabel.setText(timeFormat.format(currentTime));
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000L);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            public void setRunning(boolean isRunning) {
                this.isRunning = isRunning;
            }

        }




    /**
     *     
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {

                    framePhaseOne = new JFrame(WorldName1);

                    action  = new ActionListener()      // this is for PHASE 2
                    {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                        {
                            if (userPoints.getGamePhase())  // if F2 was clicked 
                            {
                                framePhaseTwo = new JFrame(WorldName2);
                                framePhaseTwo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
                                framePhaseTwo.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                                framePhaseTwo.setLocation(FRAME_LOCATION_X, FRAME_LOCATION_Y);
                                Renderer_PhaseTwo myCanvas2 = new Renderer_PhaseTwo(userPoints);
                                final Animator animator2 = new Animator(myCanvas2);
                                framePhaseTwo.add(myCanvas2);
                                framePhaseTwo.setSize(FRAME_SIZE_X, FRAME_SIZE_Y);
                                framePhaseTwo.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
                                    {
                                        new Thread() 
                                        {
                                             @Override
                                             public void run() 
                                             {
                                                 animator2.stop();
                                                 System.exit(0);
                                             }
                                        }.start();
                                    }
                                });

                                framePhaseTwo.setVisible(true);
                                animator2.start();
                                myCanvas2.requestFocus();
                                myCanvas2.setFocusable(true);
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    final Container contentPane = framePhaseOne.getContentPane();
                    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                    /**
                     *  the timer of the count-down
                     */

                    timer = new Timer(1000, timerAction);
                    timer.start();

                    changingLabel1 = new JLabel("Game is offline , hit Start to continue !");
                    statusBar.setLeftComponent(changingLabel1);

                    final JLabel dateLabel = new JLabel();
                    dateLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                    statusBar.addRightComponent(dateLabel);

                    final JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel();
                    timeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                    statusBar.addRightComponent(timeLabel);

                    contentPane.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                    /**
                     *  start button
                     */

                    final JButton startButton = new JButton("Start the game !");
                    // startButton.setBounds(300, 50,140, 50 );
                    startButton.setBounds(BUTTON_LOCATION_X
                                        , BUTTON_LOCATION_Y,
                                          BUTTON_SIZE_X, 
                                          BUTTON_SIZE_Y );

                    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                    {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                        {
                            start = true;       // start the game
                            userPoints.startGame();
                            contentPane.remove(startButton);
                            contentPane.revalidate();
                            contentPane.repaint();

                        }
                    });                 
                    contentPane.add(startButton);

                    framePhaseOne.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                    framePhaseOne.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                            exitProcedure();
                        }
                    });

                    timerThread = new TimerThread(dateLabel, timeLabel);
                    timerThread.start();

                    Renderer_PhaseOne myCanvas = new Renderer_PhaseOne(userPoints);
                    final Animator animator = new Animator(myCanvas);

                    Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                    BufferedImage originalImage = null;

                    try 
                    {
                        originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(HARD_TARGET));
                    } 

                    catch (Exception e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
                    Cursor newCursor = t.createCustomCursor(originalImage, new Point(0, 0), "none"); 

                    framePhaseOne.setCursor(newCursor);
                    framePhaseOne.setLocation(FRAME_LOCATION_X, FRAME_LOCATION_Y);
                    framePhaseOne.add(myCanvas);
                    framePhaseOne.setSize(FRAME_SIZE_X, FRAME_SIZE_Y);
                    framePhaseOne.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()

                    {
                        @Override
                        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
                        {
                            new Thread() 
                            {
                                 @Override
                                 public void run() 
                                 {
                                     animator.stop();
                                     System.exit(0);
                                 }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    });

                    framePhaseOne.setVisible(true);
                    animator.start();
                    myCanvas.requestFocus();
                    myCanvas.setFocusable(true);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add an `ActionListener` to a `JFrame`, it does not function like a button and so has no action listeners.

What you are looking for is a [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html). It detects mouse clicks. You may also be interested in a [MouseMotionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html) which give you information on mouse movement.

Here's an example:

```
framePhaseOne.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        System.out.println("Mouse was clicked on my frame!");
    }
};
```

MouseAdapter is an abstract class which implements MouseListener. It keeps you from having to implement all the methods required by the MouseListener interface.

Edit:

After speaking with you in comments below what you're looking for is a [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html). Again, I recommend the KeyAdapter for the same reasons as MouseAdapter. Here's an example:

```
framePhaseOne.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F2){
            //close frame one.
        }
    } 
});
```

Also do this with framePhaseTwo if you want it to close your first frame as well.

```
framePhaseTwo.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F2){
            //close frame one
        }
    } 
});
```

Please note, the frame requires focus to receive key events.

Comment: Thanks , but I can't see why `MouseListener` is what's needed in this case . What I basically want is for `framePhaseOne` to be closed when `F2` is clicked - I'm handling the clicking inside `Renderer_PhaseOne` class , that's okay . I just need to make `framePhaseOne` close itself when my boolean flag is flipped on . Any way around this `MouseListener` ?

Comment: If you want input from the frame itself in the form of a mouse click? No. If you want input from the keyboard, yes. Is that what you want? Input from the keyboard? Let me know and I'll update with an example.

Comment: @ William Morrison: Yes , from keyboard , when I'm inside the first frame : `framePhaseOne` . Much appreciated .

Comment: Edited, this should do what you require.

Comment: If this does what you require, please remember to accept the answer to close the question. You can accept by clicking the green check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the help , but hitting `F2` from inside the first frame won't invoke the keylistener , I'm trying to fix it right now .

Comment: Add a second key listener on the first frame, and have it also close the other frame. Remember, the focused frame is the one which will receive key presses.

Comment: I found the source of the problem : the class `Renderer_PhaseOne` is implementing `KeyListener` inside it , so inside `Renderer_PhaseOne` the method `keyTyped()` is `{/* blank */}` , but from Main , I'm doing what you suggested , so apparently the listening from `Main` is discarded .... WOW .

Comment: No, don't use a KeyListener! Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings. Read the tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for more information.

Comment: @ron repeating rob's comment for emphasis: **don't** use keyListeners!

Comment: Keybindings is the better choice. However keylisteners work too. The Sun tutorials refer to the two as having slightly different use cases. There is nothing fundamentally wrong with keylistener.